# What are the rules that Vala's Process.spawn_command_line_async follows in interpreting CLI arguments?

Tags: bash, email, vala

Specifically, how does it interpret arguments that are in quotes or that feature redirects from standard input (e.g. <)?

I've got the following string:

```
string cmd = "mail -s 'Work Order #%s' -c %s -r email@server.com %s < email.txt".printf(wo.get_text(), ownmail, outmail.get_text());
```

When I use

```
Posix.system(cmd);
```

The command runs as expected and an email is sent, with the body taken from email.txt.

When I use

```
Process.spawn_command_line_async(cmd);
```

I get the error from the mail command that 'option -c is not found' or words to that effect.  When I lose the quotes around Work Order #%s and instead escape the spaces, the email sends (with the subject line containing the back slashes) but instead of getting the body of the message from email.txt, it treats email.txt as another recipient of the email (it shows up in my inbox with 'email.txt' under the To: section).  The < is being ignored or dropped. To check things out, I used

```
Process.spawn_command_line_async("echo %s".printf(cmd));
```

This showed me that the quotes around the subject line were being dropped but the < was still there.  I can use Posix.system() in my program but for the sake of simplicity and reducing dependencies (and being more idiomatic), I'd prefer to use Process.spawn_command_line().  What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: The output from `echo` is going to not have the quotes if that's run by the shell because the shell will have removed them not because `spawn_command_line_async` did. You'd see to use `set -vx` in that command (assuming a shell again) to see what arguments/etc. the shell *actually* sees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to play around with `Shell.quote()` and `Shell.unquote()` in your `"".printf()` arguments.

The Vala `Process.spawn_command_line_async()` function is bound to GLib's [g_spawn_command_line_async ()](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html#g-spawn-command-line-async) function. So a good place to start looking for more details is the GLib documentation. The GLib documentation states `g_spawn_command_line_async()` uses [g-shell-parse-argv](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Shell-related-Utilities.html#g-shell-parse-argv) to parse the command line. This parses the command line so the "results are defined to be the same as those you would get from a UNIX98 /bin/sh, as long as the input contains none of the unsupported shell expansions."

Also on that page are [g_shell_quote ()](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Shell-related-Utilities.html#g-shell-quote) and [g_shell_unquote ()](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Shell-related-Utilities.html#g-shell-unquote). These functions are bound to Vala as [Shell.quote ()](http://valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/GLib.Shell.quote) and [Shell.unquote ()](http://valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/GLib.Shell.unquote).

`mail` only accepts the body of the message from `STDIN` and `g_spawn_command_line_async()` won't handle the redirect. So you will either need a command line tool that takes the body as an argument or using something like [Subprocess](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gio-2.0/GLib.Subprocess) instead.

Comment: `g_spawn_async_with_pipes ()` / `Process.spawn_async_with_pipes ()` does handle stdin. So you can set up a pipe yourself instead of relying on the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both AIThomas and Jens sending me looking in the right direction, I was able to get it working with the following code:

```
static int main(string[] args) {


    string subject = "-s " + Shell.quote("Work Order #123131");
    string cc = "-c ccemail@org.org";
    string frommail = "-r " + "senderemail@org.org";
    string[] argv = {"mail", subject, cc, frommail, "destinationemail@org.org"};
    int standard_input;
    int child_pid;



    Process.spawn_async_with_pipes (
        ".",
        argv,
        null,
        SpawnFlags.SEARCH_PATH,
        null,
        out child_pid,
        out standard_input,
        null,
        null);  

    FileStream instream = FileStream.fdopen(standard_input, "w");
    instream.write("This is what will be emailed\n".data);      

    return 0;   

}
```